# How do I send and receive data using UART on two Pi Picos?

Tags: microcontroller, uart, raspberry-pi-pico, micropython

When I connect GP4 (UART1 TX) on one pi pico to GP5 (UART1 RX) on the second pipico and vice versa, I keep getting "NONE" as my received data.

Pico #1:

```python
from machine import Pin, UART
uart = UART(1, 115200)
while True:
    uart.write("Hello")
```

Pico #2:

```python
from machine import UART, Pin
uart = UART(1, 115200)
while True:
    if uart.any():
        rcvChar = uart.read()
        print(rcvChar.decode("ascii"), end="")
```

This prints out nothing. If I continuously print `uart.read()` I get a slew of "NONE" values.

I also tried doing a loopback where I connected the TX and RX pins on one of the picos (GP0 and GP1), and sending/reading information that way using:

```python
from machine import UART,Pin
uart = UART(0, 115200)
uart.write('hello')
c = uart.read(5)
print(c)
```

And still got "NONE"
Am I missing something obvious here? Thanks in advance

Comment: What were you expecting to get?

Comment: I was hoping to get "H", "e", "l", "l", "o" back. I tried connecting the TX pin to RX and running a simple test code to see if I was receiving data and didn't get anything either, I think I might be missing some conceptual thing about using UART to send data

Comment: How are your Pis powered? Do they share a common ground wire?

Comment: Have you tried to loopback one board to itself so it can reveive the same bytes it sends?

Comment: @Justme, I think loopback is what the OP is trying to describe in their comment, though it's ambiguously written, unfortunately. OP, please edit your question to add new information, don't put it in comments. Otherwise, readers have to piece together your full question from scattered fragments. Thanks.

Comment: @TonyM I have updated the original question to discuss the loopback, thank you!

Comment: @brhans One is powered using a DC Power supply, and the other through a USB to my computer. I just tried connecting the ground pins between the two, and that got it working!! Thank you so much!!